# Bending + Contact Force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, elasticity

When we have 2 bodies in contact with each other, for example a book lying on the surface of a table. The table's molecules bend a little bit because of the weight of the book thus producing the contact force. My question is this contact force acting on the book does also bend the molecules of the book?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, standard Hertzian contact theory states that both sides of an elastic contact deform. Each deformation amount is proportional to $$\delta_i \propto \frac{1-\nu_i^2}{E_i}$$ where $E_i$ is the modulus of elasticity and $\nu_i$ the Poisson's ratio.

Answer (score 2):

In materials that are made up of small molecules, ionic lattices or atoms it is the bonding forces between those entities that get stretched a little, thereby providing an elastic response to any imposed deformation.

But in highly extendible materials made of very long chains (polymers) like rubber and plastic, the molecules do get stretched upon macro-deformation.